# "Compile error: Automation error" when VBE generates the Worksheet_Change private sub

Tags: excel, vba, automation, compiler-errors

First timer here...

I know some of you will be tempted to throw cans of beer at me for doing this, but I am using Excel/VBA to create some sort of animated GUI specification:

- I create each UI of my application in a separate sheet
- I use cells as well as I use ActiveX controls (combo, check box, etc)
- I am doing very basic UI stuff such as showing/hiding lines based on current combo box selection, automatic update of a cell based on the modification done on another cell, really no rocket science here.

Until yesterday, all was well, everything worked (more or less) and today, this shows up when I reopened my work:

[image]

Just to make it clear, I am using this to generate the code:

[image]

With a new xlsm file, this does not happen. It starts looking like a corrupted file... However I cannot afford to copy/paste all my stuff from the corrupted file to the new one because of this.

So has anyone run into this ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a VBA Cleaning Tool.

1. *Excel VBA Code Cleaner* did not do the trick.
2. *VBA Toolkit Excel Add-in powered by Ribbon Commander* did.

All is in order now.